# R remove rows after value 1 occurs

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), X1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), X1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

I have df and wish for df1; after value of X1 = 1, throw out all rows after by ID.

My attempt:

```
df1 <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(flag = cumsum(X1 == 1)) %>%
    filter(flag <= 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
subset(df, !!ave(X1, ID, FUN = \(x)rev(cumsum(rev(x)))))
  ID X1
1  1  0
2  1  1
4  2  0
5  2  1
7  3  0
8  3  0
9  3  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it with `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
    filter(
        cumsum(lag(X1, default = 0))==0,
        .by = ID
    )
#   ID X1
# 1  1  0
# 2  1  1
# 3  2  0
# 4  2  1
# 5  3  0
# 6  3  0
# 7  3  1
```